# To retrieve image from oracle database by using imagepath in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, oracle, handler

Here is the code:

```
         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        string sql = "SELECT imgpath FROM imgemp WHERE empl_code = " + id + "";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        connection.Open();

        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            //byte[] file = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("imgpath");
            //Get Image Data
            byte[] file = (byte[])reader["imgpath"];

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            memoryStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            memoryStream.Dispose();
```

When I run it I am getting the following error,

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your `MemoryStream`,  `OracleCommand`, and `OracleReader` all need to be in `using` blocks, so that they are cleaned up immediately if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read file's content not path into bytes array:

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(reader["imgpath"].ToString());
```

Comment: i tried using this but still my image is not being displayed.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for'System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string)' has some invalid arguments and  cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' - these are the errors

Comment: I am using oracle as my backend and c#

Comment: @user3168680 add to string at the end

Answer (score 0):

By the name of your field it seems that you have stored path of file in the field imgpath and now you are trying to cast it to byte[]

Comment: get the image itself.